# How do the "Level range" fields work in the AH?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have an iLvl 63 one hand mace that deals 600 DPS and has some other goodies, most notably the required level is reduced by 8. This means this particular item can be used by level 52 chars.

I checked if there were any such weapons available and found none. As my weapon surpasses every similar item I set the buyout price to 1m.

I checked the AH some hours later how my item competes, but did not find it.

My query was like this:

- 1-handed
- Mace
- Level range nothing - 52

As the weapons are sorted by DPS by default (I even selected it to be sure) my weapon should be at the top. But the first weapon listed has like 280 DPS.

I am very confused. Do the Level range fields actually address the item level instead of level required?

This would be stupid as no one would EVER find my weapon. Who looks for "Level range" max 63 and reduced level requirements 8 to find a item with requirements for level 52?

So what do the level range fields actually do, especially in the level 60 upto 63 range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The level range is the required player level (not ilevel) that the item was **prior to any "reduced level requirement"** mods.

To search for a level 60 item that has been reduced by 8 levels, you would have to search for:

- Level range: (inclusive of level 60 or just level 60)
- Modifier: Reduced Level Requirements: 8

These are very popular items though, as they grant ilevel 63 powers to level 43s (or higher). So I wouldn't worry too much about players not finding your item.

Comment: As of patch 1.04, the auction house should take reduced level requirement into effect when deciding whether an item fits into a level range.

Answer (score 1):

Level requirement reduction is not taken into account by this filter. It is a known issue. Aside from that oversight, they mean required level, not item level.